# Stack inside Stack in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to place Stack inside Stack in flutter, it dosen't work if I change position of inner Stack's positioned widgets.

works:

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 150.0,
        child: Text("Text#1"),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 100.0,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: Text("Text#2"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

If I add "top: 200.0" inside inner Stack's positioned, inner Stack disappears and flutter throws error

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 150.0,
        child: Text("Text#1"),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 100.0,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top:200.0,
              child: Text("Text#2"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
```

Comment: I know the reasons, but I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you using a `Positioned` to mimic the behavior of `Padding`?

Comment: I have some chart built based on Stack and I want to make those charts be swiped like in Tinder so I pack those charts in another stack

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can wrap your second **[Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)** With **Container** with **height** and **width** property.

Stack fill height and width of parent widget but in your case height and width of parent widget is not define as it is a Stack Widget. if you define the size of parent widget so that stack widget can Positioned their child widget from their start point.

```
  Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        top: 350.0,
        child: Text("Text#1"),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 100.0,
        child: Container(
          height: mediaQueryData.size.height,
          width: mediaQueryData.size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top:200.0,
                child: Text("Text#2"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: i just updated my answer i hope that you get better idea .

Comment: You saved me from a minor headache